# Problem adding a behaviors element to my WCF client config

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-phone-7, config

I'm trying to add a behaviors element to my client config file so I can specify maxItemsInObjectGraph.

The error I get is: The element 'system.serviceModel' has invalid child element 'behaviors'. List of possible elements expected: 'bindings, client, extensions'.

Here is my config:

```
<configuration>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_KernService" 
          maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceViewEventBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/KernMobile.WCF/KernService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_KernService"
        contract="KernWcfService.KernService" name="BasicHttpBinding_KernService"
        behaviorConfiguration="ServiceViewEventBehavior" />
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

It's also complaining about the behaviorConfiguration attribute in the endpoint element.

Any ideas? .Net 4.0 BTW.

EDIT: I should also point out that this is in a WP7 project.

Comment: I suppose the error you are referring to appears in Visual Studio Error List. Correct?

Comment: I get a squiggly blue line in the editor and the error appears in a tooltip when I hover over. If I run the app I get an invalidoperationexception thrown in the service client constructor: Unrecognized element 'behaviors'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WCF concept of behaviors doesn't exist in the Silverlight 4 (WP7) version of system.ServiceModel.

You'll need to specify the DataContractSerializer options elsewhere (either in another config section or in code)

Same goes for behaviorConfiguration on client/endpoint.

Reference this MSDN for the config description:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd540827(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Do you need to?  In Silverlight it defaults to Int.MaxValue

Comment: Was too caught up trying to updating it manually that I missed this. Thanks!